# @HostListener not triggering when used on Angular Directives

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Angular9 and have created an accordion component that when used, looks like the snippet below.
I'm trying to capture click events on the header

```
  <accordion>

    <div accordionItem [expanded]="false">
      <div *accordionItemHeader>
        HEADER1
      </div>
      <div *accordionItemBody>
        BODY1
      </div>
    </div>

    <div accordionItem [expanded]="true">
      <div *accordionItemHeader>
        HEADER2
      </div>
      <div *accordionItemBody>
        BODY2
      </div>
    </div>

  </accordion>
```

The actual accordion component looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "accordion",
  templateUrl: "./accordion.component.html"
})
export class AccordionComponent {

  @Input()
  collapsable: Boolean = false;

  @ContentChildren(AccordionItemDirective)
  items: Array<AccordionItemDirective> = [];

}
```

```
<div>
  <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index">

    <ng-template ngFor let-header [ngForOf]="item.headers">
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="header.template">
      </ng-template>
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template ngFor let-body [ngForOf]="item.bodies">
      <ng-template [ngIf]="item.expanded">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="body.template">
        </ng-template>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-template>

  </ng-template>
</div>
```

AccordionItem is simply a directive that contains ContentChildren:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[accordionItem]",
  providers: []
})
export class AccordionItemDirective {

  @Input() expanded: Boolean = false;

  @ContentChildren(AccordionItemHeaderDirective)
  headers: Array<AccordionItemHeaderDirective> = [];

  @ContentChildren(AccordionItemBodyDirective)
  bodies: Array<AccordionItemBodyDirective> = [];

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(param: any) {
    console.log("click item")
  }


}
```

AccordionItemHeader:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[accordionItemHeader]",
})
export class AccordionItemHeaderDirective {

  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<any>) {
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(param: any) {
    console.log("click header")
  }

}
```

Neither the `@HostListener` in the `AccordionItem`, nor the `AccordionItemHeader` is triggering the `onClick` function when being clicked on. What is the correct way to trigger a function on click on the header in Angular9?

One workaround is to wrap the headers in divs and add (click) handlers on them, but would prefer the click handler to be on the original element that the `*accordionHeaderItem` directive is on.

**EDIT**: Here's a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kjvjde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) as requested.

Comment: Please provide a https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, I've added a Stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by using directives without the star.

The star means you have to manage the component rendering yourself, without the star, the component is rendered as is and you can attach things with HostBinding.

See [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tycxw4?file=src/app/app.component.html)

The guts of the component is as follow:

```
<div accordion>
  
  <div accordionItem [expanded]="false">
    <div accordionItemHeader style="background-color: red; cursor: pointer;">
      HEADER1
    </div>
    <div accordionItemBody style="background-color: blue">
      BODY1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div accordionItem [expanded]="true">
    <div accordionItemHeader style="background-color: red; cursor: pointer;">
      HEADER2
    </div>
    <div accordionItemBody style="background-color: blue">
      BODY2
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Accordion Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[accordion]"
})
export class AccordionDirective {

  @ContentChildren(AccordionItemDirective)
  items: Array<AccordionItemDirective> = [];
  
}
```

AccordionItemDirective:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[accordionItem]",
  providers: []
})
export class AccordionItemDirective {

  @Input() expanded: Boolean = false;

  @ContentChildren(AccordionItemHeaderDirective)
  headers: Array<AccordionItemHeaderDirective> = [];

  @ContentChildren(AccordionItemBodyDirective)
  bodies: Array<AccordionItemBodyDirective> = [];

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(param: any) {
    console.log("click item")
  }

  updateBodies() {
    this.bodies.forEach(body => {
      if (this.expanded) {
        body.styleDisplay = null;
      } else {
        body.styleDisplay = "none";
      }
    });
  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.headers.forEach(header => {
      header.click = () => {
        this.expanded = !this.expanded;
        this.updateBodies();
      };
    });
    this.updateBodies();
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty("expanded")) {
      this.updateBodies();
    }
  }
}
```

AccordionItemHeaderDirective:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[accordionItemHeader]",
})
export class AccordionItemHeaderDirective {
  
  @HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick($event: MouseEvent) {
    this.click();
  }

  click = () => {
    console.warn("click handler not handled");
  };

}
```

The AccordionItemBodyDirective hides / show the body using a HostBinding:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[accordionItemBody]",
})
export class AccordionItemBodyDirective {

  @HostBinding("style.display")
  styleDisplay: String = null;

}
```